# Thread local storage (TLS) - Compiler error

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, powerpc

I have declared a variable:

static __thread int a;

I am getting the following error:

fatal error (dcc:1796): __thread not supported in the specified target environment

How can I resolve this? Should I enable some flags in make file?

I am on windriver compiler(compiling for powerpc). I referred to similar questions but unable to figure out.

Basically I am trying to make re-entrant functions. Any suggestion would be of great help.

Is there anything I can by including pthread.h?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your reentrancy requirements?

Answer (score 3):

__thread is gcc extension which is not working on all platform. As mentioned above you could use pthread_setspecific/ pthread_getspecific, there is an example from man:

```
          /* Key for the thread-specific buffer */
          static pthread_key_t buffer_key;

          /* Once-only initialisation of the key */
          static pthread_once_t buffer_key_once = PTHREAD_ONCE_INIT;

          /* Allocate the thread-specific buffer */
          void buffer_alloc(void)
          {
            pthread_once(&buffer_key_once, buffer_key_alloc);
            pthread_setspecific(buffer_key, malloc(100));
          }

          /* Return the thread-specific buffer */
          char * get_buffer(void)
          {
            return (char *) pthread_getspecific(buffer_key);
          }

          /* Allocate the key */
          static void buffer_key_alloc()
          {
            pthread_key_create(&buffer_key, buffer_destroy);
          }

          /* Free the thread-specific buffer */
          static void buffer_destroy(void * buf)
          {
            free(buf);
          }
```

But as I see you are trying to make re-entrant functions, reentrant function should not hold static non-constant data.

Comment: How do you know OP needs/wants reentrancy? Indeed, `pthread_once` is not reentrant, but that's irrelevant unless you intend to call this code from a signal handler, and even then you might be able to make it irrelevant.

Comment: My bad, somehow I missed that one line. Still I would question whether OP actually wants reentrancy. Lots of people use the word incorrectly to mean thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will try out. I actually have code that is not re-entrant. I need to convert the same to re-entrant in the shortest possible manner. I do have some file scope static variables. Hence I want them to have seperate addresses when different threads access them. Thats what I want.. and I hope thats what is re-entrancy.

Answer (score 2):

`__thread` is an extension. The POSIX thread interfaces to accomplish similar things are  `pthread_getspecific` and  `pthread_setspecific`

Comment: Thanks. In my case can you show me a simple example? Whatever I search regarding this is too complex as I am using this for the first time.

Comment: @kartik, tvn basically shows you how this works. But all of this is probably not so much a good idea if you really want to be re-entrant. You'd have to do the `pthread_key_create` somewhere in `main` before you spawn any of your threads.